# JS Fetch api and Symfony2 FOSRestBundle

Tags: javascript, php, json, symfony

Currently I am trying to get a response from my Symfony2 FOSRest Controller using Javascript Fetch API. In my controller I am serving a response with the following code:

```
return View::create()
    ->setStatusCode(200)
    ->setData(array('success'=>true));
```

And in my JS I am getting it with this:

```
fetch(url, 'get').then(
    function (response) {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Problem, status: ' +  response.status);
            return;
        }
        response.json().then(function (data) {
            console.log('OK');
            if (typeof callback == 'function')
                return callback(data);
        });
    }
).catch(function (err) { 
    Console.log(err); 
});
```

As a result my controller is giving me a pure json which I can see (in Chrome Dev Tools under Response section) if I type my url directly into browser, but when js code is executed I see the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

which is related to my initial file which begins from !doctype html. In my debugger if I log response.body I see that it is ReadableByteStream, but not my json. I think that the problem is somewhere in Symfony because I can read my json if I send it from regular .php file but not from RESTFul controller. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPD:**
when I changed response.json() to response.text() I finally got the data)) Is there any reason for that? And in addition in my url I have query string parameters (like ?par1=1&par2=2) which I want to pass to my REST Controller and which I get when I again type my url into browser directly with the following method:

```
$data = $request->query->get('data');
```

But when I pass it with JS fetch (in url parameter) no data is transferred to controller. Any idea what to do in this case? Thank You

**UPD2**
My symfony config.yml

```
fos_rest:
param_fetcher_listener: true
body_listener: true
format_listener: true
view:
    formats:
        json: true
        xml: false
        html: false
        rss: false
    templating_formats:
        json: false
        xml: false
        html: false
        rss: false
    view_response_listener: 'force'
```

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: true }

Comment: Please post your Symfony config files - that's probably where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your config :

```
fos_rest:
    # ...
    view:
        # ...
        formats:
            json: true
```

If it doesn't work, add the following :

```
fos_rest:
    # ...
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/yourApiPrefix', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
```

Comment: Just tried your variant and the others as described here [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/format_listener.html) but still getting 406 and No matching accepted Response format could be determined. As for passing parameters to controller from query string I tried Request Body Converter Listener but still no use(( Maybe there is some good verified method to decode query string in a controller?

Comment: Also it's surely not related to FOSRest config. Have you tried to render a JsonResponse with the same content ? like `return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true));` , don't forget the use statement. If it doesn't work, it's not a symfony2 problem.